# Having a hard time reloading UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working with the following class which successfully loads a row to the UITableView.

```
import UIKit
import ResearchKit

enum Activity: Int {
    case Demographics

    static var allValues: [Activity] {
        var idx = 0
        return Array(anyGenerator{ return self.init(rawValue: idx++)})
    }

    var title: String {
        switch self {
        case .Demographics:
            return "Demographics"
        }
    }

    var subtitle: String {
        switch self {
            case .Demographics:
                return "Demographics Survey"
        }
    }
}

class ActivityViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard section == 0 else { return 0 }

        return Activity.allValues.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("activityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        if let activity = Activity(rawValue: indexPath.row) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = activity.title
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = activity.subtitle
            if (activity.title == "Demographics"){
                if (Data().is_demo_complete()){
                    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
                    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
                    cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
                }
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

    func reloadtable(){
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDelegate

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        guard let activity = Activity(rawValue: indexPath.row) else { return }

        let taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController
        switch activity {
            case .Demographics:
                taskViewController = ORKTaskViewController(task: DemoTask, taskRunUUID: NSUUID())


        }

        taskViewController.delegate = self
        navigationController?.presentViewController(taskViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have another class called `Data` where I store all communications to my server.  The idea is that I have to check some data on the server to know whether or not to grey out and disable one of the rows in the tableView.  From the data class, when the server call is completed and successful, i do this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    ActivityViewController().reloadtable()
})
```

I have confirmed, that successfully calls the `reloadtable()` function, in which it runs `self.tableView.reloadData()`.  The place I am stuck is that after that, the tableView doesn't actually reload.  I can tell because I put a breakpoint on the line that says `if let activity = Activity(rawValue: indexPath.row) {` and the breakpoint does not get triggered a second time, even though I can confirm that the `reloadtable()` function is indeed triggered.  What am I doing wrong here, why isn't the table being reloaded?  Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is the `Data` class:

```
class Data: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate {

    var unique_id = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString;

    var demo_complete = false

    func check_demo_complete(){

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://www.myurl.com/is_demo_complete.php")!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "unique_id=\(unique_id)&pass=somepass"
        request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            if ( responseString == "true" ) {
                self.demo_complete = true
                print ("Demo has been completed")
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    ActivityViewController().reloadtable()
                })
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func is_demo_complete() -> Bool{
        return self.demo_complete
    }


}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `self.tableView.dataSource = self` ?

Comment: the lines that show up in the table are defined in an `enum` in the same swift file but outside the class definition.  Not really sure what you mean.  But you can see i have a filter inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: When a `UITableView` `reloadData()` gets called, it will call information from its `UITableViewDataSource`. From your code, `ActivityViewController` should be the dataSource of `self.tableView`.

Comment: Thanks so much, so I edited my question and added the `enum` section.  I was thinking that `reloadData()` would just run through the routine again and re-add all the rows.  You're saying that if the data source is not changed, then it knows it doesn't need to reload?

Comment: From what I understand of the question is that you want to reload the TableView from within another class. Shoudn't you create an object reference in the AppDelegate and in the viewDidLoad() of the ActivityViewController call yourObjName = self. Then in your data class you can call the function yourObjName.reloadtable()

Comment: Well yes you're right I am trying to reload that tableView from another class.  Thats why I put the `reloadtable()` function there.  Using a breakpoint I did confirm that the function was being called successfully.  What you're saying is that that won't work for some reason?  I am still getting used to iOS dev with swift, so this technique of putting an object reference in the AppDelegate file I'm not familiar.

Comment: What does your 'Data' comms class look like, and how/where is the comms call triggered? What you're doing when your comms finishes is creating a new instance of 'ActivityViewController', and calling the reload data function on the new instance (your breakpoint will hit, but on your new, wrong instance). If your comms call if triggered from inside 'ActivityViewController', pass 'self' into the comms function, when it finishes call a function on that instance.

Comment: @Simon thanks for the help.  I have included the Data class in my question.  The original comms call is triggered from the `viewDidLoad()` function of the main ViewController of the program, which is another third class, NOT the ActivityViewController that I have listed here.

Comment: I'm not at a computer so I can't provide code but you could use NSNotificationCenter here. When your comms completes post a notification 'DemoComplete'. Your ActivityViewController can register for this notification and reload the table when triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `ActivityViewController().reloadtable()` call. This creates a new `ActivityViewController` each time your `Data` class downloaded data. It is important that you'd only call `reloadtable()`on the same `ActivityViewController` instance that already exists (and that is displayed on screen).

One good (basic but simple) solution would be to do the following refactoring :

```
func check_demo_complete(completion:(Bool -> ()){
  // your network call
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    if ( responseString == "true" ) {
      completion(true)
    }
    else {
      completion(false)
    }
    // or, simpler : completion(responseString == "true")
  }
}
```

That way, by calling `check_demo_complete()`, you'd be obligated to pass a closure :

```
if (activity.title == "Demographics"){
  Data().check_demo_complete() { [weak self] success in
     if success {
       // change your textColors etc
       self?.tableView.reloadData()
     }
  }
}
```

Again, this is a basic solution that should work. The important lesson to learn is : don't create new instance of classes each time you need them.

Comment: Holy Sh*t it worked.  Thank you so much!  Now i just see that the server call is made repeatedly, i really just need it to be made once, but I can't probably figure it out from here.  You gave me a technique here that is REALLY useful!

Comment: That's because the request is made in `cellForRow`, meaning each time a cell is displayed.

Comment: Yeah i noticed that and then it calls to reload the data from inside that function... Is it possible to call to reload the table from outside the `cellForRow`?

Comment: Sure. In your case, that's even better

Comment: Since I only need to check the server once (for now), I just take out the reload data line, and it loads the table correctly once and thats it.  Its perfect.  Thanks so much.